# Properly Configuring A-Records in Virtualmin for DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, godaddy, a-record

I'm trying to configure my own DNS with Virtualmin for a domain that I registered through GoDaddy.  However, after following the instructions of GoDaddy's support staff, I still can't successfully ping my domain.  They told me that everything is configured correctly on the GoDaddy end and that my A-records look fine (see below) in the following note:

> This seems to be an issue with the server. I show Godaddy has your nameservers setup correctly however it looks like the server many not be configured with these nameservers/domain. We would recommend reviewing the server to make sure the domain is configured properly on that side.

**In my GoDaddy Control Pannel**
I've configured both my nameservers as

- NS1.UPSMART.com
- NS2.UPSMART.com

and I've also configured my Host Names with my two ip numbers

- 199.21.115.174
- 75.127.14.195

**In my Virtualmin Records file, I have**

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA NS1.UPSMART.COM. root.NS1.UPSMART.COM. (
            1387829375
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
@   IN  NS  NS1.UPSMART.COM.
@   IN  NS  NS2.UPSMART.COM.
UPSMART.com.    IN  A   199.21.115.174  
www.UPSMART.com.    IN  A   199.21.115.174
ftp.UPSMART.com.    IN  A   199.21.115.174
m.UPSMART.com.  IN  A   199.21.115.174
localhost.UPSMART.com.  IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.UPSMART.com.    IN  A   199.21.115.174
admin.UPSMART.com.  IN  A   199.21.115.174
mail.UPSMART.com.   IN  A   199.21.115.174
UPSMART.com.    IN  MX  5 mail.UPSMART.com.
UPSMART.com.    IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:UPSMART.com ip4:199.21.115.174 ?all"
```

My question would be if anyone can think of something that I might me leaving out.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem. But since you have obfuscated everything, it's difficult to be sure. You may need to post the real domain names/IP addresses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Thanks for the response; and sorry for how delayed mine is (I've been moving between Christmas and New Years).  Anyway, I updated the above with the actual ip numbers and domain name to be used, as per your recommendation.  Let me know if this helps anything, if you have a chance.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see an obvious problem with your zone. You don't have address records for your two nameservers, ns1 and ns2. You need to have them *both* in your zone file, and in GoDaddy's control panel as glue records.

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I missed that!  Thanks so much, it worked perfectly.